# Segmentation fault in va_args parsing

Tags: c, malloc, segmentation-fault, variadic-functions

Why does the code below gives `EXC_BAD_ACCESS, could not access memory`?

```
int combine_strings(char **outputStr,...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char *s, *out=0;
    int len=0;

    va_start(ap,outputStr);
    while(s=va_arg(ap,char *))
    {
      len+=strlen(s);
    }
    va_end(ap);


    if(!(out=malloc(len+1)))
        exit(1);

    *outputStr=out;

    va_start(ap,outputStr);
    while(s=va_arg(ap,char *))
    {
      len=strlen(s);
      memcpy(out,s,len);
      out+=len;
    }
    va_end(ap);

    *out=0;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have to disagree with the other previous posters. The original code does not iterate over the same `va_list` twice. It creates two different ones and iterates over each of them in turn, even though the same variable is used to hold both lists.

In fact, I managed to run the function properly. Hence, my guess is that the problem is in how the function was called. Here is how I called it, note the trailing `NULL` and the setup of the `output` parameter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// ... combine_strings() goes here...
int main()
{
  char * res;
  char * * output = &res;
  combine_strings(output, "FOO", "BAR", "BAZ", NULL);
  printf("%s\n", *output);
}
```

The code above outputs `FOOBARBAZ` as expected.

Comment: +1: The standard (7.15.1.4) specifically says "The va_start macro **initializes ap** for subsequent use by va_arg and va_end."

Comment: You are correct! It had issue with the way it was called. it would give segmentation fault if we pass ZERO instead of NULL as last argument. if we pass 0 then we should typecast it to (void*)0, I was passing a 0, and hence it gave segmentation fault.

Comment: If a pointer is larger than a plain int, then that would account for the need of the explicit pointer cast, or NULL. ps. Don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted when you are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot iterate over the same `va_list` twice. You need to create a copy using `va_copy()`.

```
int combine_strings(char **outputStr,...)
{
    va_list ap, ap2;
    char *s, *out=0;
    int len=0;

    va_start(ap,outputStr);
    va_copy(ap2, ap);
    while(s=va_arg(ap2,char *))
    {
      len+=strlen(s);
    }
    va_end(ap2);


    if(!(out=malloc(len+1)))
        exit(1);

    *outputStr=out;

    while(s=va_arg(ap,char *))
    {
      len=strlen(s);
      memcpy(out,s,len);
      out+=len;
    }
    va_end(ap);

    *out=0;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using va_start twice in one function is difficult to get to work on all platforms.  See [here](http://qnxcs.unomaha.edu/help/product/neutrino/lib_ref/v/va_arg.html#Coercion) for more information.

Probably best to use [va_copy](http://qnxcs.unomaha.edu/help/product/neutrino/lib_ref/v/va_copy.html).

Comment: The link you provide as a reference describes a completely different problem than "using va_start twice in one function".

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to answer this kind of question is to run it in a debugger. You'll get a full stack trace, code pointer, and you'll be able to look at the values of all the variables.

To use [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), first compile the program with debugging symbols (`-g` in gcc). Then, run it:

```
gdb program_name
(gdb) run
```

It will crash and you'll be able to see why.